# Inject phtml block into customer_address_edit

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, module

Is it possible to inject a phtml block into the customer_address_edit view only?

In my module layout xml config i'm trying:

```
<customer_address_edit>
   <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="core/template" name="customer_mymodule_edit" template="mymodule/customer/mystuff.phtml"/>
    </reference>            
</customer_address_edit>
```

This isn't working. If I change `<customer_address_edit>` to `<customer_address_form>` the block appears in the new address page and the edit page. I need it only in the edit page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a look on `AddressController`, you can see that, for both `edit` and `new` actions, the action controll is fully forwarding to `form` action. This in effect makes only one handler that is available for both `edit` and `new` actions, which is `customer_address_form`. This means we cannot use `customer_address_edit` or `customer_address_new` in layout files.

An alternative solution that we can rely on is add your block in `customer_address_form` itself and create a logic that differentiate both actions in the template file. So try this.

File : `local.xml`

```
<customer_address_form>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="core/template" name="customer_mymodule_edit" template="mymodule/customer/mystuff.phtml"/>
    </reference> 
</customer_address_form>
```

In your template file, use this condition in order to ensure `edit` action is taking place

File: `mystuff.phtml`

```
//ensure edit action is taking place
if(explode("/",$this->getRequest()->getPathInfo())[3] == 'edit'){

     //your codes come here
}
```

When we are in `edit` page, `$this->getRequest()->getPathInfo()` will return a  value like this `customer/address/edit`. What we are doing here is, retrieve the third part of the path and check whether it is `edit` or not.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it. That did help a lot.